# Add contact with Family name first

Tags: android, android-contacts

Consider the code below. As an example, if `displayName` = "Squirrel, Rocky J." then it appears in the contacts as "Rocky J. Squirrel". I would like to be entered as is, i.e. "Squirrel, Rocky J." However in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.html), I don't see that as an option.
How do I do this?

```
if (displayName != null) {
    contentProviderOperationArrayList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    displayName)
            .build());
}
```

Edit:
After changing the settings as suggested by marmor ... if I have "Leo Tolstoy" and "Langston Hughes"
I would expect to see the contact list as:

H
Hughes, Langston
T
Tolstoy, Leo

Instead I see (on Samsung SM-T530)

L
Hughes, Langston
Tolstoy, Leo

(on Pixel C)

H
Langston Hughes
T
Leo Tolstoy

So not only does the display seem to be device dependent and confusing, it appears it cannot be controlled programmatically.

Comment: Consider to use DISPLAY_NAME_ALTERNATIVE (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactNameColumns.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a contact (either programatically or via the contact-edit screen), the `Contacts` content-provider parses the inserted name, and attempts to split it into the name fields: `prefix`, `first`, `middle`, `last`, `suffix`, `nickname`.

After which a name can be shown in the `Contacts`/`People` app either as "`First Last`", or "`Last, First`", depending on settings.

If you which to toggle the name display option:

> In the stock `Contacts` app, click on menu > `settings` > `Name
>   Format` > select `Last name first`.

**UPDATE**

System contacts apps can be a bit different between devices, but most display at least two options in the above settings page: `Sort by` and `Name format`.

From the examples you gave above, I think you'd want to change both settings to `Last Name`.

Regarding changing those values programatically, this might be possible, depending on the permissions your app has, something like this:

```
Settings.system.putInt(getContentResolver(),"android.contacts.SORT_ORDER", value);
```

where `value` is `1` or `2`.
Read  this to understand the permissions needed: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#canWrite(android.content.Context)